# ubuntu coldfusion server cannot establish connection

Tags: ubuntu, coldfusion

I installed ColdFusion on my new computer.  Ubuntu 14.04 ColdFusion8 apache.  The first time I tried this:

```
`http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`
```

I got into the administrator just fine.  I did part of my setup, but then had to stop to look something up.  There were updates waiting so I installed those and restarted the computer.

Now when I type in the above URL I get:

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8500.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Check to see if the ColdFusion service is running. Check in the log files to see if any errors are being reported. Why did you install ColdFusion 8?  It is VERY old and no longer supported.

Comment: try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. I know it should not matter...but I have seen issues with this in the past.

Comment: Miguel -- I thought I had checked, but I was wrong, it was not running.  When I started it up my problem went away.  Re why version 8, that is my test version, and I don't believe Adobe will let me download another.  I will buy the product as soon as I finish testing my application, which was nearly done when the machine crashed and I had to get a new one.  Then of course I have to retest in the later version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried RAILO?